# Taking User Input Keyword & Running it in Windows Shell with Os Module

Tags: python, python-3.x, operating-system

I was Wondering If it is possible to Take User Input Keyword & Run it  in Windows Shell with Os Module imported

example `
import os

Give_Input=("something")
os.popen('ls',Give_input ').read()
         `
i know os.popen('Give_input ').read()  will work directly.. i wanted to know if there is some way to get it work with ls example as mentioned above 
Thanks

Comment: do u want to take direct input ?

Comment: yes user will be be providing  Input from shell only , & will get output in shell itself

Comment: try this 
string_is =  input("Please enter a string:\n")

Comment: Thanks for the reply .. i know string_is will work  , i wanted to know if i can somehow use it with  os.popen('Some command',string_is ').read()  .... For example if use give input D: & in place of somecommand i give dir den expected output shld be dir D: